# NIFI - Throttling warning

Tags: apache-nifi

On one of our NIFI instances, when we are in a backlog state,we encounter the throttling warning quite frequently. We have tuned the indexing threads and also upped the resources (CPU) allocated to the VM.  What other things should we be looking at to identify what is causing the contention that is resulting in throttling? Obviously could be disk I/O, but when looking at the monitoring, nothing is jumping out there. Any suggestions on what others do to further investigate, would be greatly appreciated.

NIFI Version: 0.6.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would focus on disk contention.  Are the flowfile, content, and provenance repositories all on the same physical partition?  If yes then almost certainly it is disk contention related.  A great command to use for this is 'iostat'.  You can typically run something like 'iostat -xmh 5' and watch for utilization.

Now even on a well configured system it is possible to have just such a high rate of data that provenance indexing simply cannot keep up. These cases are fairly rare and almost always easily addressed by reducing the number of individual items floating around the flow (leveraging batching where appropriate).

There have been considerable performance related improvements since the 0.6.1 release regarding provenance handling and that may or may not help your case.

Worse case scenario is that you can switch to transient provenance which is all in memory and only keeps 100,000 recent events by default.

Comment: Thanks Joe. As always appreciate the info and feedback. We will take a look given your suggestions.